# Display Button before lock screen in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

Can we display button before lock screen from my blackberry application? I knows that we can check programmatically device is locked or not but can we display our application screen before lock screen?

Answer (score 0):

I presume here that you are talking about BBOS devices (Java devices).  If you are not, please clarify your question.

Also, when you say "before lock screen", I presume you mean that you want your screen to appear on top of the lock screen, so that the lock screen is (at least partially) hidden by your new screen.

There has been a few Threads discussing this on the official BB Java forum, for example this one:

[Global screen restrictions](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/pushGlobalScreen-restrictions/m-p/19550)

The short answer is that the lock screen is using a screen priority that is not accessible to third party developers, meaning that it is not possible for 3rd party developers to put a screen on top of the lock screen.

In short, the answer to your question is no.  And there is no workaround either, nor any indication from RIM (now BB) that there ever will be a method.

Sorry.